# build stages using parameters from a function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

getting this error when tried to build stage using a method :
java.lang.StackOverflowError: Excessively nested closures/functions at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:14) - look for unbounded recursion - call depth: 1025
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsFunction.invoke(CpsFunction.java:28)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsCallableInvocation.invoke(CpsCallableInvocation.java:54)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:102)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:80)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor275.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:146)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:146)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

```
//@Library('shared-library')_
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
      // booleanParam(name: 'TEST', defaultValue: false, description: 'Set to true to run tests')
       booleanParam(name: 'DEPLOY', defaultValue: false, description: 'Set to true to deploy')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Automate') {
            steps {
                script {
                    //def automateScript = libraryResource('vars/automate.groovy')
                    //def automate = load automateScript
                    call(DEPLOY: params.DEPLOY)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
def call(Map parameter)
{
    stage('deploy')
    {
        when {
            expression {
                parameter.DEPLOY == true
            }
        }
        steps{
            echo"Hello"
        }
    }
}
```